# Local GeoServer public access

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I need to know if WMS of geoserver with "localhost" url linked in openlayers or leaflet code will show on public access by other users/clients or will not be shown?

Answer (score 5):

No, it will not be visible to anyone but you. When a user displays your webmap, the code will try to read from **his** computer (`localhost`), which doesn't have a running Geoserver, and will fail.